# How to escape {{ braces }} in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't think I can use `ng-non-bindable`, as my string is in a tooltip (3rd party library), the value of the string is set in the controller.

```
<span tooltip="ctrl.myString"></span>
```

Controller.js:

```
var myString = "some string {{ with braces }} somewhere";
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
myString = myString.replace('}}', '}\}');
```

Comment: Updated...hope that's better.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the { with the ASCII representation? &#123;
var myString = "some string &#123;&#123; with braces &#125;&#125; somewhere"

Comment: Hmm just tried that, but that still evaluates to 0.

Comment: Maybe `"{{ 'some string {' + '{ with braces }' + '} some where'}}"`? I havn't tested it. But maybe worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

```
<code ng-non-bindable>{{ string here }}</code>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ### Escaped Interpolation
>
> `$interpolate` provides a mechanism for escaping interpolation markers. Start and end markers can be escaped by preceding each of their characters with a REVERSE SOLIDUS U+005C (backslash). It will be rendered as a regular start/end marker, and will not be interpreted as an expression or binding.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $interpolate Service API Reference - Escaped Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)